# fine-tuning `array` environment for writing system of equations

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays

I have heard that the `array` environment can be highly customized, but I am confusing in writing the following system (this system is from Lagrange's method of variation of parameters for linear ODEs)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
C_1'\cos t+ C_2'\sin t +C_3'&=&0\\
-C_1'\sin t+ C_2'\cos t &=&0\\
-C_1'\cos t+C_2'(-\sin t)&=&\dfrac{1}{\cos t}
\end{array}
$$
\end{document}
```

I want to align `C_1'`, `C_2'`, `=` (and in other cases with `C_3'` also).

How should I write it?

**Update:** Bernard gave a nice answer using `amsmath` only. Now I can apply for a related system. About the number `3`, from [amsmath document](http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf), `alignat` takes one argument, the number of
“equation columns”: count the maximum number of &s in any row, add 1 and
divide by 2. In this case, (5+1)/2=3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
& C'_1 & \cos t &+ C_2'\sin t +&C_3'& e^{2t} =0\\
- & C'_1 & \sin t & + C_2'\cos t +2&C_3'&e^{2t}  =0\\
- & C'_1 & \cos t & -C_2'\sin t+4&C_3'&e^{2t}  =\frac{1}{\cos t}
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Standard remark: `$$....$$` does not belong in latex documents.

Comment: @daleif Thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest to realise this alignment with `alignat`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
 & C'_1 & \cos t &+ C_2'\sin t +C_3'& & =0\\
- & C'_1 & \sin t & + C_2'\cos t & & =0\\
- & C'_1 & \cos t & +C_2'(-\sin t)& & =\frac{1}{\cos t}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

For a possible alignment of C3 (irrelevant here), you just have to add another alignment column.
[image]

Comment: Nice `alignat`! only `amsmath` is needed

Comment: With your current setup, there's inadequate spacing between `C'_1` and `\cos t`/`\sin t` in the first column. How might one fix that?

Comment: @BlackMild: Thank you for your kind appreciation! I often use alignat, because one has full control on the spacing between the alignment columns

Comment: @Mico: I didn't feel it necessary, because I often find the constant factors, especially when they're in uppercase, too close to he functions, and I tend to add a  thin space. But if one  prefers a smaller space, `\!` should do it, or maybe  `\mkern -2mu`.

Comment: @Bernard - My apologies for apparently being rather unclear. I would actually advocate *increasing*, not decreasing, the amount of whitespace between `C'_1` and the various trig terms.

Comment: To increase the spacing (unnecessary in my opinion) it should be enough  to add a positive spacing/kerning between `&`  and, say, `\cos t` in the first equation

Comment: I thought I was pretty familiar with the `amsmath` environments, but I didn't remember `alignat`.  How is it different from `align`?

Comment: @LSpice: The main differences are that, by default, there is no spacing between alignment columns: you have to introduce one by hand in the most relevant row if you want one, and that you have to specify the number of alignrnent points as an argument of the environment. Here I added no spacing, to make the equations look natural, and there are 3 alignment points (hence 2×3 - 1 ampersands).

Comment: @Bernard when I add a left brace to the system, I get an error: Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures;(amsmath) trying to recover with aligned. \end{alignat*}. How does it can be fixed? `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%\[\left\{
\begin{alignat*}{4}
 &C'_1 \cos t &+& C_2'\sin t   &+& C_3\;&=&0\\
-&C'_1 \sin t &+& C_2'\cos t   & &      &=&0\\
-&C'_1 \cos t &+& C_2'(-\sin t)& &      &=&\frac{1}{\cos t}
\end{alignat*}
%\right.\]
\end{document} `

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}             % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{C}{>{{}}c<{{}}} % for relational and binary operators

\begin{document}
\[
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\begin{array}{lClClCl}
\hphantom{-}C_1'\cos t &+& C_2'\sin t &+& C_3' &=& 0\\
-C_1'\sin t            &+& C_2'\cos t & &      &=& 0 \\
-C_1'\cos t            &-& C_2'\sin t & &      &=& 1/\cos t,\quad \cos t\ne 0.
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! So LaTeX's `array` (and `tabular`) is not enough for this, and we need `array` package ? https://mirror-hk.koddos.net/CTAN/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf

Comment: @BlackMild - The `array` package provides the very useful command `\newcolumntype`; that's why I load the `array` package in the answer given above. If you don't want to load the package, that's fine; you'd have to replace `\begin{array}{lClClCl}` with `\begin{array}{l>{{}}c<{{}}l>{{}}c<{{}}l>{{}}c<{{}}l}`, though. Ouch! The `array` package has some other useful features, such as providing the column types `m`, `b`, `w`, and `W`. Please see table 1 in the package's user guide for all "goodies" provided by the package

Answer (score 6):

A variation of @Mico's solution without the `array` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mathsep}{%
  \sbox0{$=$}%
  \sbox1{$\null =\null$}%
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{\dimexpr 0.25\wd1-0.25\wd0}% 2\arraycolsep per &
}

\begin{document}

\[
\mathsep
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}%
\begin{array}{lclclcl}
\phantom{-}C_1'\cos t &+& C_2'\sin t &+& C_3' &=& 0\\
-C_1'\sin t &+& C_2'\cos t & &      &=& 0 \\
-C_1'\cos t &-& C_2'\sin t & &      &=& 1/\cos t,\quad \cos t\ne 0.
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Just out of idle curiosity: Is there anything wrong with using the `array` package? :-) More seriously, by using the `r` column type for the first column, the contents of that column end up aligned vertically on the `t` terms (of `\cos t` and `\sin t`, and no longer on the `C` terms, as was requested by the OP>

Comment: @Mico - No, but the OP seemed to be avoiding it.  And I will put the \phantom back in.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I try avoiding it because I am just familiar with `amsmath`, `amssymb`. Thank you for an alternative solution!

Answer (score 6):

Another possibility is to use the systeme package which does the setup automatically.
It is very convenient to use for simple systems of equations.

A fault, the doc is in French !!! (A quality for me)

https://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}


\syssubstitute{{a}{C_1}{b}{C_2}{c}{C_3}}
\systeme[abc]{
a\cos t+ b\sin(t) +c=0,
-a'\sin t+ b\cos(t) =0,
-a\cos t-b\sin(t)=\dfrac{1}{\cos t}
}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had thought this morning to same package :-) +1