# Multiple align in formulae

Tags: align, cases

I'm trying to write down a system of equations with variable alignment:

```
1 x + 2 y + 3 z = 4
5 x       + 6 z = 7
8 x + 9 y       = 10
```

but if you try using align and &&, then unwanted indents appear before the plus signs:

```
\begin{align}
&& 1 x && + 2 y && + 3 z &= 4  \\
&& 5 x &&       && + 6 z &= 7  \\
&& 8 x && + 9 y &&       &= 10
\end{align}
```

[image]

How can this be formalized so that there are no such indents? How is it possible to add a curly brace here in order to make it in the style of the `cases` environment? Is it also possible to achieve a neat alignment in the case of negative first coefficients?

If you use the `matrix` environment (or an improved version of `matrix*` with `[r]` alignment), then there are unnecessary indents:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{matrix}
1 x &+& 2 y &+& 3 z &=& 4  \\
5 x & &     &+& 6 z &=& 7  \\
8 x &+& 9 y & &     &=& 10
\end{matrix}
\right.
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: You can try systeme package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's as easy as [`\usepackage{systeme}`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/systeme).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{systeme}

\begin{document}

\[
\systeme{
1 x + 2 y + 3 z = 4,
5 x       + 6 z = 7,
8 x + 9 y       = 10
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As long as I understand your question, `array` environment from `amsmath` can also align equations by adding extra fields around variables, coefficients, and operators:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \arraycolsep=3pt
    \def\arraystretch{1.25}
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{rcrcrcr}
          x & + &   y & - & -700z &=& -400 \\
        -5x &   &     & + &     z &=& 7 \\
         8x & - &  9y &   &       &=& 10
    \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

It also lets you control alignments (left, centre, right) as well as spaces: between rows and between columns by setting `\arraycolsep` and `\arraystretch`, accordingly.

[image]

Comment: nice use of `array`! Note that we can add some negative blank `\left\{\!\!`

Answer (score 1):

An use of `alignat` from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/618542/140722).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{4}
& &x& +2&y& -3&z& =4\\
-&5&x&    && +6&z& =7\\
&8&x& -9&y&   & & =10.
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `IEEEeqnarraybox` environment from the [`IEEEtrantools`](https://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran?lang=en) package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}
\[
\left\{
\begin{IEEEeqnarraybox}[\relax][c]{rrrCl}
    1 x &{} + 2 y &{} + 3 z &=& 4,\\
    5 x &{}       &{} + 6 z &=& 7,\\
    8 x &{} + 9 y &{}       &=& 10%
\end{IEEEeqnarraybox}
\right.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]